# Java Time API get offset from sql Timestamp given the Chronology

Tags: java, jdbc, java-8, jodatime

I have the following code which gets offset from sql Timestamp object using the Joda Time Library.

```
public static long getOffset(Chronology chronology_, Timestamp timeStamp_)
  {
    long offset = 0;
    if (chronology_ != null)
      {
        offset = chronology_.getZone().getOffset(new DateTime(timeStamp_).getMillis());
      }
    return offset;
  }
```

How can achieve the same using Java 8 API. I am not sure if chronology is required any more.

Comment: I think the problem can be resolved before calling this method, in another word you don't need to get `Timestamp` from your database. If you show us how to get timeStamp_ maybe we can propose a proper solution

Comment: This is a utility code and I have an sql timestamp. I dont control how we get timestamp

Comment: A `java.sql.Timestamp` is intended to be timezone-less, except it isn't due to a historical poor design decision. You should switch to using to `java.time.LocalDateTime` (or for with time zone types in the database to `java.time.OffsetDateTime`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Joda-Time concept of a chronology and the java.time (JSR-310) concept of a chronology are similar, there is a difference that matters in your situation: The Joda-Time `Chronology` may (optionally) have a time zone. The `java.time.chrono.Chronology` cannot. So you need to provide the time zone to use for the operation in some other way than through a chronology.

Now we’re at it, I might suggest that you also provide the point in time in some other way than through a `java.sql.Timestamp`. So one option would be:

```
public static long getOffset(ZoneId zone, Instant when)
{
    long offset = 0;
    if (zone != null)
    {
        int offsetSeconds = zone.getRules()
                .getOffset(when)
                .getTotalSeconds();
        offset = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(offsetSeconds);
    }
    return offset;
}
```

If your caller has got an old-fashioned `Timestamp` from a legacy API that they cannot change, they should convert. So one way of calling the above method would be:

```
    long offsetMillis = getOffset(
            ZoneId.of("Africa/Khartoum"), theirTimesatmp.toInstant());
    System.out.println(offsetMillis);
```

An example output using a timestamp from around now:

> 7200000

The `Timestamp` class is poorly designed, a true hack on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date` class, so we should not use it. If we can’t avoid getting one, we should convert it to either `Instant` or `LocalDateTime` immediately and perform or further work from there.

A further nice improvement will be if your method returns the `ZoneOffset` object returned from `getOffset()` rather than a number that may leave a caller wondering whether it’s seconds, milliseconds or some other unit.

If you do insist on providing a convenience method that accepts a `Timestamp`, you may of course add a wrapper that is friendly to the past. For example:

```
/** @deprecated use {@link #getOffset(ZoneId, Instant)} instead */
public static long getOffset(ZoneId zone, Timestamp timeStampParam)
{
    return getOffset(zone, timeStampParam.toInstant());
}
```

**Link:** [Converting from Joda-Time to java.time](https://blog.joda.org/2014/11/converting-from-joda-time-to-javatime.html) on Stephen Colebourne’s blog